# Rename multiple files, add date in the middle

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, solaris, mv

I want to rename all files in a folder, including a current time stamp in the name, retaining the original extension, in Solaris, like this:

test1.txt > test1.date.txt

I tried this, but I lose the first part of the name:

```
find * -prune -type f -name '*.txt' -exec mv {} {}.$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M').txt \;
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```bash
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c '
    now=$( date +%Y%m%d%H%M )
    for pathname do
        mv "$pathname" "${pathname%.txt}.$now.txt"
    done' sh {} +
```

This would find all pathnames of regular files in or below the current directory, whose names end in `.txt`.  For batches of these, a short shell script is called.  This script will first get the timestamp (this is had only once for each batch, for efficiency) and then loop over the given pathnames.

For each pathname, it will rename it by removing the final `.txt` (using `${pathname%.txt}`), and adding a dot, the timestamp and `.txt`.

This has not been tested on Solaris, but uses only standard components and options etc.

To compute the timestamp only once, before calling `find`, use

```bash
now=$( date +%Y%m%d%H%M ) \
find ...as before (but without assigning to now)...
```

or

```bash
env now="$( date +%Y%m%d%H%M )" \
find ...as before (but without assigning to now)...
```

(note the line continuations in the above two commands)

If the files are located in a *single* directory, just run the loop:

```bash
now=$( date +%Y%m%d%H%M )
for pathname in ./*.txt; do
    mv "$pathname" "${pathname%.txt}.$now.txt"
done
```

This assumes that the pattern `./*.txt` matches all names that you'd like to rename.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

---

Your `{}.$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M').txt` does not work portably.  It may work with some implementations of `find`, but an implementation is not required to expand `{}` to the current pathname if the `{}` occurs together with another string.

The relevant text from [the POSIX standard is](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html):

> A `utility_name` or argument containing only the two characters `{}` shall be replaced by the current pathname. **If a `utility_name` or argument string contains the two characters `{}`, but not just the two characters `{}`, it is implementation-defined whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without change**.

Comment: You might want `mv -- fname ...` in case the names start with hyphens

Comment: @D.BenKnoble They won't start with dashes.  `find` will add the search path (at least `./`) to each pathname, and the loop alternative will also always have `./` before any filename due to the way I wrote the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, though am not sure how `solaris` compatible it is....

```
from=txt
to=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).txt
find * -prune -type f -name "*.$from" -exec sh -c 'mv "$3" "${3%.$1}.$2"' sh "$from" "$to" {} ';'
```

Stolen shamelessly from the [unix.stackexhange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find) link given by @Kulasananda but I like the way that the call from `sh` composes the variables for `sh -c mv`.

Sweet.